# Data extraction from wef output file

Tags: python, netcdf4

I have a wrf output netcdf file.File have variables temp abd prec.Dimensions keys are time, south-north and west-east. So how I select different lat long value in region. The problem is south-north and west-east are not variable. I have to find index value of four lat long value

Comment: Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask & https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

1) Change your Registry files (I think it is Registry.EM_COMMON) so that you print latitude and longitude in your wrfout_d01_time.nc files.
2) Go to your WRFV3 map.
3) Clean, configure and recompile.
4) Run your model again the way you are used to.

Comment: I have only nc file , no other file available except this. Each file have hourly data